# Can we use select to Accept() from different listeners in Go?

Tags: go, goroutine

Just as the following codes:

```
for {
    select {
    case conn, err := listener1.Accept():
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        go handleConn1(conn)
    case conn, err := listener2.Accept():
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        go handleConn1(conn)
    }
}
```

While the editor tells me something wrong with `select`

Can we implement something like this in **Go**?

Comment: Since `Accept()` is not a channel, but a regular function, you need goroutines to call `Accept()` simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` only works with channels (see more here: https://gobyexample.com/select)

In your case, you could span two goroutines so that each of them waits for the `Accept` of one listener and processes the connection:

```
go func() {
    for {
        conn, err := listener1.Accept():
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        handleConn1(conn)
    }
}()
go func () {
    for {
        conn, err := listener2.Accept():
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        handleConn2(conn)
    }
}()
```

Comment: With a version downloaded in 2018, I cannot declare anonymous goroutines like that.

Comment: I've edited the code to correct the goroutine syntax.